C# .NET Maui Publishing with CLI "Error: Input file with '.DLL' extension not supported"
I am trying to publish an update for a .NET Maui app that has been in production for over a year. I've made several updates to the app, without issue. However, I recently had to get a new computer, and now I am unable to update the app. I am using (and have used) the following method to publish from the CLI, using PowerShell from a Visual Studio terminal:
dotnet publish myapp.csproj -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64

In the past, this has given me the desired msix package, which I am able to share with my team who needs to run the program. However, I am now encountering the following error when I run this publish command:

Error: Input file with '.DLL' extension not supported.

I have looked high and low for a solution to this, read up on similar issues, but nothing seems to be the same as my issue. I have tried to clean/rebuild, unload/reload my project, and have reviewed all my properties and settings, but am unable to see anything there that would suggest changing it might fix the problem. I have also deleted the folder containing the solution, and re-cloned the entire thing from github. I have restarted my computer, restarted and updated Visual Studio.
Per @Serg's suggestion, I ran the build with the -bl flag. This gave me a different, unexpected error that I hadn't seen before:

error: Packaged .NET applications with an app host exe cannot be ProcessorArchitecture nuetral. Please specify a RuntimeIdentifier or a Platform other than AnyCPU.

I updated my .csproj file to specify an x64 platform, with a runtime identifier of win-10-x64. I have added the following to the top-level  of this file, as well as the conditional  for release and all others (!= ''):
<Platforms>x64</Platforms>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>

Both problems still persist.

You can try to get binlog (dotnet build -bl) then use the MSBuildStructuredLogViewer to find more details about the root of the problem. If you still have access to the old computer, you can get the same log there then compare logs.

After a lot of banging my head against the wall, on a whim I tried to pack my .csproj file to see if that would give me anything useful, and it did! Specifically, it led me to adding the following to my csproj file:
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>
</PropertyGroup>

After adding this, I was able to publish successfully.
